# Heroku app change: db migration (pg and MongoHQ)

Tags: heroku, mongohq

I had and app on heroku 
then I decided to create another app (on cedar stack which does not support stack:migrate).

How can I migrate databases PG and MongoHq?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can migrate MongoHQ by logging into heroku and clicking on addons => mongohq. From the application, create a new user under Database Users named "backup" with a simple password. Below, my password was "temppw". Then click the Database Info tab for your connection information (host:port [flame.mongohq.com:27049] and dbname [appXXXXXX]). Then just call mongodump to get a backup.

```
mongodump -h flame.mongohq.com:27049 -d appXXXXXX -u backup -p temppw
```

This will make a local directory called "dump" containing your data. Verify it is there by loading it into a local db (just run mongorestore and look in your local mongo install) - because when you destroy your old app, it destroys the MongoDB (heroku also destroys your postgres db - so you should do this for that as well).

Anyway, do the same as above to your new application database, except use mongorestore.

```
mongorestore -h flame.mongohq.com:27049 -d appXXXXXX -u backup -p temppw dump/appXXXXXX
```

**DO NOT JUST POINT THE ENVIRONMENT URLS**. This is dangerous, because deleting your initial app will destroy all of your data.

Comment: MongoHQ has been renamed Compose FWIW.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about MongoHQ but as for PostgreSQL, you can use [Heroku Taps](http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/3/18/push_and_pull_databases_to_and_from_heroku/) to pull the data from the remote database to your local machine. You could then push it to the new app.

Alternatively you could change the environment variable `DATABASE_URL` of your new Cedar app to point to the database being used by the old app - **assuming you're not using the shared database**.

This last approach would also work for MongoHq.

Comment: Thanks, actually I'm more interested in mondodb migration. I haven't tried to change MONGOHQ_URL on new app yet, but I thought maybe there is some standard solution for that purpose.

Comment: perhaps this can help: http://support.mongohq.com/customer/portal/articles/100129-migrate-local-db-to-mongohq